# How to map String[] to PostgreSQL array column in mybatis

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

my table in postgreSQL is

```
create table x (feature varchar[]);
```

I want to use the method "selectOne" to select an array, here is my configuration of mybatis

```
<resultMap id="array" type="java.util.Map">
    <result property="feature" column="feature" typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.ArrayTypeHandler"></result>
</resultMap>

<select id="selectArrayFeatures" resultMap="array">
        SELECT feature FROM x LIMIT 1
    </select>
```

and here is my code

```
sqlSession.selectOne("PostgreEx.selectArrayFeatures");
```

the returned value is a Map<String, String[]> object. the key of map is useless for me. I only want to get the String[] value.
This is what I want to do.

```
String[] arr = sqlSession.selectOne("PostgreEx.selectArrayFeatures");
```

But I don't know how to write the code.

Comment: Is it OK for you to use Java interface mapper (i.e. writing SQL in `@Select` annotation) instead of XML mapper?

Comment: Is there any different between XML mapper and annotation?

Comment: Yes, there is, but it still is not so elegant. Your current solution (i.e. get as a `Map`) probably is the simplest at the moment.